# implementing Webcam into Browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, request, webcam

I was interested in replicating a Face detection AI I saw on YouTube. The goal was to implement the Webcam into the Browser, to then see the live result of the AI on the screen. I am using Live-Server in Visual Studio to directly show the edited code on my screen.

Following things were tried to fix the issue:

- Changeing the resolution of the camera in the code to the supported one
- Trying to use another webcam with higher resolution than 640 x 480
- Giving the browser every access permission
- Deactivating all extensions of the browser to see any changes
- Using different browsers
- Using a different funktion to use the video of the webcam

The following code contains the code for the camera. All other files are not in relation to the problem.

The JS code:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
    { video: true },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
  }, 100)
})
```

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="face-api.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    canvas {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay muted></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the way you use `getUserMedia()` is incorrect. [It only takes in a single parameter and uses promises for the rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#parameters). Try using it like this

```js
const video = document.getElementById('video')

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: Thank you. As a 15 year old who is aspiring to get a software developer guys like you, are motivating me.  god bless you

Comment: @N_Radziszewski If you are 15 and doing stuff this advanced you are going to be very good very quickly! Good luck with it! 